# Problem with OpenCL

Tags: memory-management, opencl

I'm facing a problem with OpenCL and I hope someone will have a hint on what the cause might be. Following is a version of the program, reduced to the problem. I have an input int array of size 4000. In my kernel, I am doing a scan. Obviously, there are nice ways to do this in parallel, but to reproduce the problem, only one thread is doing the entire computation. Before the scan, the input (result_mask) has only values 0 or 1.

```
__kernel void
sel_a(__global db_tuple * input,
      __global int * result_mask,
      __global int * result_count,
      const unsigned int max_id)
{
// update mask based on input in parallel

mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

if(gid == 0)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < max_id; i++)
    {
        if(result_mask[i]!=0)
        {
            c++;
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
    }
    *result_count = c;
}
}
```

The expected result would be the number of elements that initially had a value different than 0 and nothing but 5's in the result mask. However, that is not the case. The output looks like this:

```
...
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
...
```

I get this block of 80 elements somewhere after approx. 3200 elements. It's not always the same positions, but it's always the same amount of elements - 80. And it get's even weirder - if I change the first line to 
    if(gid == 2000)
the problem is gone. However, after playing around with the thread id, I've come to the conclusion that the problem isn't gone, it just moved. Using thread 1425, I get the problem half the time and when I get it, buggy block is at the end of the array. Hence I assume, when I don't have the 0s and 1s, the block has "moved" further back. For some more excitement - when I increase the input size to 5000, the output consists entirely of 0s. Furthermore, the following code won't work:

```
if(gid == 0)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < max_id; i++)
    {
        if(result_mask[i]!=0)
        {
            c++;
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
    }
    *result_count = c;
}
if(gid == 3999)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < max_id; i++)
    {
        if(result_mask[i]!=0)
        {
            c++;
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
    }
    *result_count = c;
}
```

whereas only

```
if(gid == 3999)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < max_id; i++)
    {
        if(result_mask[i]!=0)
        {
            c++;
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            result_mask[i] = 5;
        }
    }
    *result_count = c;
}
```

will work (again, probable with a larger input, it might not work). Following are some details on the device:

```
Device name: GeForce 9600M GT
Device vendor: NVIDIA
    Clock frequency:        1250 MHz
    Max compute units:      4
    Global memory size:     256 MB
    Local memory size:.     16 KB
    Max memory allocation size: 128 MB
    Max work group size:        512
```

Obviously, I am missing out something big here. My first thought was it's some memory conflict, where the block of 80 elements is overridden by another 'thread'. But the more I think about it, the less sense it makes.

I'll be very grateful for any hints!
Thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry for the late response. So I've modified the code, reducing it to a minimum to reproduce the problem. Following is the c-code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <OpenCL/openCL.h>

#define INPUTSIZE (200)

typedef struct tag_openCL
{
    cl_device_id        device;

    cl_context          ctx;
    cl_command_queue    queue;
    cl_program          program;
} openCL;

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    openCL* cl_ctx = malloc(sizeof(openCL));

    if(!cl_ctx)
        exit(1);

    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &cl_ctx->device, NULL);

    cl_ctx->ctx = clCreateContext(0, 1, &cl_ctx->device, clLogMessagesToStdoutAPPLE, NULL, &err);

    cl_ctx->queue = clCreateCommandQueue(cl_ctx->ctx, cl_ctx->device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);

    printf("Successfully created context and queue for openCL device. \n");

    /* Build program */

    char * kernel_source = "__kernel void \
sel(__global int * input, \
    __global int * result_mask, \
    const unsigned int max_id) \
{ \
    int gid = get_global_id(0); \
    \
    result_mask[gid] = input[gid] % 2 == 0; \
    result_mask[gid] &= (input[gid] + 1) % 3 == 0; \
    \
    if(gid == 0) { \
        int i; \
        for(i = 0; i < max_id; i++) { \
            if(result_mask[i]) { \
                result_mask[i] = 5; \
            } \
            else { \
                result_mask[i] = 5; \
            } \
        } \
    } \
}";

    cl_program prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(cl_ctx->ctx, 1, (const char**)&kernel_source, NULL, &err);
    cl_ctx->program = prog;

    err = clBuildProgram(cl_ctx->program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(cl_ctx->program, "sel", &err);

    /* create dummy input data */
    int * input = calloc(sizeof(int), INPUTSIZE);
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < INPUTSIZE; k++)
    {
        input[k] = abs((k % 5) - (k % 3))+ k % 2;
    }

    cl_mem source, intermediate;

    unsigned int problem_size = INPUTSIZE;

    source = clCreateBuffer(cl_ctx->ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, problem_size * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cl_ctx->queue, source, CL_TRUE, 0, problem_size * sizeof(int), (void*) input, 0, NULL, NULL);

    intermediate = clCreateBuffer(cl_ctx->ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, problem_size * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);

    int arg = 0;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, arg++, sizeof(cl_mem), &source);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, arg++, sizeof(cl_mem), &intermediate);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, arg++, sizeof(unsigned int), &problem_size);

    size_t global_work_size = problem_size;
    size_t local_work_size = 1;
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cl_ctx->queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    clFinish(cl_ctx->queue);

    // read results
    int * result = calloc(sizeof(int), problem_size );
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(cl_ctx->queue, intermediate, CL_TRUE, 0, problem_size * sizeof(int), result, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFinish(cl_ctx->queue);


    int j;
    for(j=1; j<=problem_size; j++)
    {
        printf("%i \t", result[j-1]);
        if(j%10 ==0 && j>0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result is still non-deterministic, I get 0's and 1's at random positions in the output. For a local workgroup size of 1, they are in the first half of the array, for a size of 2 - in the second half, for a size of 4 it looks okay for 200 elements, but there are again 0's and 1's for a problem size of 400. Furthermore, for a global work group size of 1, all works fine. That is, if I use two kernels - one to do the parallel computation with a global work group size of [problem size] and a second one with a global work group size of 1, everything works great. Again, I'm am perfectly aware that this is not the way to do it (a kernel running such sequential code), however, I'd like to know, why it's not working, since it looks I'm missing something out.

Thanks,
Vassil

Comment: As Josep said, can you post the setup code and also the code that you have removed from your kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OpenCL code is very simple and the results very weird. I think that the problem can come from the setup part. Buffer creation, call to EnqueueNDRange, etc. Could you post the setup part? I guess the problem can be there.

EDIT:
After seeing your code and testing it I realized that at first I didn't fully understand your problem. As  you comented the mask updating part my mind just got rid of that line. I should have been able to answer correctly the first time.

The problem is that you CAN'T synchronize different work groups. The CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE affects the memory ordering access of the work group (making sure that writes to global memory are done before reading back). The real solution to your problem is execute your code in two calls, first you update the mask in parallel and then do the rest of the stuff in another kernel that will be executed when the first one finishes. You need the whole operation to finish before continuing, so you have to use barriers at command-queue level. There is no other way.

Verbatim from the specification:

> There are two domains of synchronization in OpenCL:
>
> - Work-items in a single work-group
> - Commands enqueued to command-queue(s) in a single context

Comment: Okay, as I wrote, I managed to get it working that way (split the kernel in two different ones and execute them one after the other). I just though it's also possible to do it in one kernel, since I wasn't aware of the mentioned 'limitation'. Thank you very much for clearing this up!